# Event target changes in jquery randomly

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery

I have a number of hyperlinks in a `ul`, and I want to capture clicks on the hyperlinks

The structure of div is as below,

```
<div style="margin:3%;" id="city-list">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="b"  data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Filter Cities...">
            <?php foreach($cities as $city): ?>
            <li>
                <a id="city_<?php echo $city['city_id'] .'_'. $city['city_name']?>" href="#">
                    <span style="font-size: 14px;"><?php echo $city['city_name']; ?></span><br/>
                </a>
            </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            <li class="no-results" style="display:none;">No results found.</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

The `jQuery` code to capture the click is below,

```
$("#city-list").delegate('a','click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
     //       console.log(event.target);
    var city_id = event.target.id,
    service_type = "<?php echo $service_type; ?>";
    JE.search_regions(city_id, service_type);
    $.cookies.set('city_id', city_id);
});
```

This works most of the time, except at some random times.

That time, the `event.target` is the `span` inside the `a` tag. I dont know why this happens.

Please help me to debug this.

Comment: in IE, FF, Chrome, Safari and Opera? In other words: do you see the same behaviour in another browser?

Comment: Have you tried using `this.id` instead of `event.target.id`? jQuery should set `this` to the `a` tag that was clicked.

Comment: Does using $(this) return a different result?

Comment: `e.target` is the actual element clicked, so if you click the `span` `e.target` will be the `span` element, but the click bubbles up and the function will still run even if it's attached to a parent element. To reference the `a` element use the `this` keyword instead.

Comment: @adeneo, that's good information, you should post it as an answer.

Comment: @rene i checked mainly in chrome. i didnt test in another browser

Comment: @adeneo, please post it as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`e.target` is the actual element clicked, so if you click the `span` element, `e.target` will be the `span` element, but the click bubbles up to parent elements, so the function will still run even if it's attached to a parent element, which is natural as the `span` is inside the `a`, and a click on the `span` is also a click on the `a` element, but `e.target` will identify exactly what element actually received the click.

To reference the `a` element use the `this` keyword instead, which will reference the bound element, in this case the `a` element.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use

```
var city_id = jQuery(this).attr("id");
```

rather than

```
var city_id = event.target.id;
```

Cheers!